# (Hyper)Surface of Simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, metric-tensor

How can I determine the surfaces of simultaneity if I know the metric? In particular, what are the surfaces of simultaneity for rotating disk with Langevin metric:
$$
ds^2=-(1-\omega^2r^2)dt^2+2r^2\omega d\phi dt+dr^2+r^2d\phi^2+dz^2
$$
where $\omega$ is a constant angular velocity?

Comment: What's a "surface of simultaneity"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind That's my question too! I think it's the surface that is orthogonal to time axis.

Comment: There is no unique "time axis" in a general Lorentzian manifold. The closest you will get are everywhere future-directed timelike vector fields, but even those do not always exist, and they are not unique in any sense. In other words, unless you can define "surface of simultaneity", I don't think this question is answerable.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok. Perhaps I should edit my question. A disk rotates about z-axis with angular velocity with respect to an inertial system (Minkowski space). Now I want to determine the surface of simultaneity. Could I explain my question more precisely?

Comment: @ACuriousMind - I guess the problem is that OP has heard the term "Surface of Simultaneity" somewhere and is not able to make sense of it. I guess the question could be resolved if we were to figure out what that means. OP, can you help us explain the context in which this was introduced to you?

Comment: @Prahar I encountered this when I wanted to determine the possibility of clock synchronization of a rotating system with respect to Minkowski space. We know that the metric in such a system has the form which I wrote it. Now I want to get the surface (or hypersurface) of simultaneity.

Comment: The problem is that "surface of simultaneity" is not, to my knowledge, a technical term, so I'm not sure what kind of surface you are looking for.

Comment: One of the most basic results in special relativity is that distinct events which appear simultaneous in one inertial frame do not appear so in another.  Since all inertial frames are equally valid it immediately follows that there *is* no well-defined 'surface of simultaneity'.  So what you are seeking does not exist.

Comment: I saw this come up in the review queue and honestly it's not well-posed enough to reopen. The term 'surface of simultaneity' is plenty clear to me (i.e. a submanifold of dimension 3 all of whose tangent vectors are spacelike) but as Timaeus's answer shows these are far, far from unique, and specifying a metric does little to whittle them down. Given that the OP is long gone (apparently this was their only post) and can't clarify the question, it's best left closed; if people want this reopened then the best shot is to ask again, mindful of the nonunicity problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recall how there are multiple surfaces of simultaneity in special relativity? Same thing in general relativity.

Recall how in special relativity you can pick one vector somewhere and find a single surface of simultaneity that has all its tangent vectors be spacelike everywhere and be orthogonal to that one single timelike vector at that one event?

That one isn't true in general relativity. Multiple surfaces could have all spacelike tangent vectors everywhere and be orthogonal to that one timelike vector at that one event.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to actually find the surfaces.

Comment: @0celo7 The grammar of the original question made it sound like they wanted an invariant foliation. This edit makes it sound like they want a formula for every possible spacelike surface? Or every inextendable one? Either way, sure, now that it's been edited I'll just delete my answer when I get to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, a simple change of variable on the angular coordinate can separate the time variable and show that the (local) surface of simultaneity is always the 3d Euclidian space, or else, always has a 3d Euclidian metric:

Define $\phi = \phi' - \omega t$, such that
$$
d\phi = d\phi' - \omega dt
$$
and substitute in the original expression defining the metric:
$$
ds^2 = -(1 - r^2\omega^2)dt^2 + 2r^2 \omega ( d\phi' - \omega dt) dt + dr^2 + r^2 ( d\phi' - \omega dt)^2 +dz^2 =\\
= -dt^2 + r^2\omega^2 dt^2 + 2r^2 \omega d\phi' dt - 2r^2 \omega dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 d\phi' ^2 + r^2\omega^2 dt^2 - 2r^2 \omega d\phi' dt + dz^2 =\\
= -dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 d\phi' ^2 + dz^2 = -dt^2 + d\sigma^2
$$
where $d\sigma^2 =  dr^2 + r^2 d\phi' ^2 + dz^2$ is obviously the Euclidian metric in cylindrical coordinates.

In other words, the metric describes 3d space as seen from a locally rotating frame given by $\phi' = \phi + \omega t$.